# Как измерить скорость работы программы?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, производительность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно точно проверить скорость выполнения какой-то части кода и всей программы на С++.

Comment: Под "скоростью" имеется ввиду время выполнения?

Comment: В общем, непонятно что за "скорость", но профайлеры специально заточены под измерение времени выполнения отдельных кусков кода.

Comment: @outcast, да, время выполнения

Comment: Если профайлер по каким-то причинам не пригоден - можно использовать системные функции типа GetTickCount() для получения времени в начале и в конце участка кода. Только время выполнения должно быть много больше, чем 1 единица времени этих функций.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а что делать в случае если скорость выполнения меньше, только профайлеры?

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter если меньше еще можно использовать, если и оно слишком грубое - профайлеры и ручной анализ.

Comment: а скорость замерять нужно в какой операционной системе?

Comment: @perfect, мне и для windows и для linux подойдёт, но насколько я понял предыдущие советы только для винды были

Comment: сейчас код напишу

Comment: rdtsc - кроссплатформенно на x86/x64

Comment: Для тех кто работает не в VS, конструкция выглядит не _asm { rdtsc }, а asm ("rdtsc");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем, вам нужен профайлер, который покажет сколько какой участок кода работал, сколько раз вызывался и т.п.
Если профайлер по каким-то причинам не пригоден - можно использовать получение времени в начале и конце участка кода, но время исполнения участка кода должно быть много больше кванта времени.
Конкретные способы:

- time() - кроссплатформенно, квант 1 с.
- GetTickCount() - Win, квант 1 мс.
- QueryPerformanceCounter() - Win, кванты мелкие.
- rdtsc - любая ос на x86/x64, считает такты процессора

Comment: Поэтому время выполнения должно быть много больше 1 мс.

Answer (score 11):

## std::chrono

Для измерения интервалов времени в С++ есть `std::chrono::steady_clock` и `high_resolution_clock`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    delete new int(1);

    auto end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    std::cout << elapsed_ns.count() << " ns\n";
}
```

Точность зависит от ОС, high_resolution_clock может быть точнее чем steady_clock, однако они могут быть не монотонными (на них может влиять синхронизация времени ОС).

## Инструкция rdtsc

Для очень маленьких интервалов времени можно использовать инструкцию процессора `rdtsc` (ReaD TicS Counter), которая возвращает количество тактов процессора. В VC++ для этого есть интринсик `__rdtsc()`, в G++ надо использовать встроенный ассемблер. Однако для правильных измерений с помощью rdtsc надо соблюсти несколько условий:

- перед `rdtsc` надо выполнить инструкцию `cpuid`, чтобы очистить конвейер процессора
- надо отключить Hyper-Threading, если он включен
- надо исключить влияние переключения контекстов потока - измерение должно быть коротким (менее 20 мс на Windows), надо принудительно переключить контекст потока перед началом измерений (`SwitchToThread` в Windows), желательно привязать поток к одному ядру процессора (у каждого ядра свой счетчик тактов).
- не надо пытаться переводить такты во время, т.к. частота процессора может меняться.
- из результата надо вычесть время работы инструкций cpuid и rdtsc (~100 тактов).

Примерный код выглядит следующим образом (Windows, MS VC++):

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template<typename F>
long long measure(F&& f) {
  const auto N = 10;
  long long results[N];

  for (auto& r : results) {
    std::this_thread::yield();
    __asm xor eax, eax
    __asm cpuid // есть интринсик, но мы хотим проигнорировать результат cpuid
    auto start_time = __rdtsc();

    f();

    __asm xor eax, eax
    __asm cpuid
    r = __rdtsc() - start_time;
  }

  auto median = results + N / 2;
  std::nth_element(results, median, results + N);
  return *median;
}

int main()
{
  auto overhead = measure([]{});
  auto ticks = measure([]{
    delete new int(1);
  });

  std::cout << ticks - overhead << " ticks\n";
}
```

Comment: Этот ответ должен быть принят, т.к. он единственный, который содержит релевантную C++ информацию.

Answer (score 4):

вот код замера времени для консольных приложений

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline _int64 HightTime(){
    _asm{
        rdtsc
    }
}

_int64 pft_start;
_int64 pft_finish;

#define SPEED_START_CONSOLE pft_start = HightTime();
#define SPEED_FINISH_CONSOLE pft_finish = HightTime(); cout << pft_finish - pft_start << endl;


int main(){
    SPEED_START_CONSOLE // точка времени старта замера скорости

            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++); // запускаем цикл для примера

    SPEED_FINISH_CONSOLE // конец измерения, выводит потрченное процессорное время (в тактах)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо хороший человек буду теперь знать и про это